# Handling multiple HTML submit button presses from form in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

So I’m running a WordPress site and it has a form I have made using HTML with a text field, an email field, a password field, and a submit button.

The problem is that users can spam the submit button, and users are occasionally prone to do that as I’m using AJAX to handle the form submission which can take a while.

Any elegant solutions would be good. I have a few suggestions I think could work but I’m not sure how to implement them, if they will actually work, or if they’re even viable.

First possibility I’m thinking of — when WordPress loads a new page, it often has the swirly loading screen with a grey background. could I have the loading screen come on prematurely, as in at the point when I run any AJAX code, too, rather than just when it changes page?

Second possibility I’m thinking of — is there a way to block all of the form fields and the submit button from being pressed as soon as you click it so it cannot be spammed and fields cannot be changed? Could this work via JavaScript (sorry not the best with JS)?

Third possibility I’m thinking of — is there a way that the system only accepts one form from an IP in the space of 5-10 seconds and any other submissions of a POST request in that cooldown time are ignored?

Would any of the above solutions work or be viable enough to work? If so, how would or could they work? I’m thinking the second one is probably the easiest to implement? However, wouldn’t the first one confirm to the user that we’re processing their data so it’d be better for the UX?

Fourth possibility that considers UX and the solution I feel is more practical — is there a way to block the submit buttons and input fields from being pressed or edited once the submit button has been pressed once, and then have a swirly loading bar appear below or above it (maybe via CSS and HTML?) so users know the site is doing something or loading?

Something just to note — the change must be client side only and the change should not affect the user if they come back to the page in future, meaning it should not remain blocked if they refresh the page or come back to it later. I know it’s implied, but wanted just to specify that.

Comment: Block the form after submitting (disable form, submit button etc),  show that the request is in progress, once AJAX results are back, take appropriate action. Also, read the [help] and take the [tour] to learn how to ask a question more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this as an AJAX request, i imagine you currently have some javascript tied to the `onsubmit` event. Most likely this function of yours encodes the data to JSON and then sends it to the server using ajax.

One way you could accomplish this, is:

Introduce a new variable in the global scope (so outside of the `onsubmit`-handler); like `var submission_cache = '';` or the like.

Next, *inside* your `onsubmit` handler, between the stage where you have 'encoded the entire form to a single json string' and the stage where you 'actually send the data', you compare the json to the `submission_cache` variable. If it matches you ignore the submission, if it doesn't match then you store a copy of the json (or a sha1 checksum of it) in `submission_cache`, and then just continue with the ajax stuff.

---

This way:

Since it is a variable on the page, the cache has the same lifetime as the page. If they leave your site and return later, the variable will be empty again, and they can submit identical info as the last time.

Secondly, if they notice they made a typo 1ms after they submitted, they **can** resubmit (since the cache wont match), which i imagine is desirable.

---

Another solution that you could use in addition to the above is to simply enable the `disabled` attribute on the submit button (inside your `onsubmit` handler function. Re-enable it after a `setTimeout` or in one of your ajax `onreceived`/`onerror` closures.